# Stimulus Pack is gone from MW2?

Tags: call-of-duty-modern-warfare-2

I was considering buying the Stimulus map pack the other day, but then I noticed that you no longer have the option to go into a Stimulus game anymore from the menu.  Would that change if I had Stimulus or can I not play it outside of private matches anymore?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Stimulus Pack maps are now included in the regular playlists: so if you choose the Demolition playlist for example, there's a pseudo-random chance that you will play a map from the Stimulus Package. To be sure, you can play these maps outside of private matches, but you have to rely on the luck of the draw.

You are correct in thinking there are no longer dedicated Stimulus Package playlists. These have been replaced by playlists for the Resurgence Pack.

Comment: I see.  They keep the maps out of regular rotation for a while and then phase them in, so if I had the stimulus pack, then I would play with other people with stimulus pack now, I hope.